# how to use discount coupon?

Tags: commerce

I installed [Commerce Coupon](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon) module

I didn't use the coupon percentage module. I created a custom coupon type which has 5 custom field, coupon_code, coupon_number_of_uses, coupon_owner, coupon_percentage and coupon_date. Then I created an instance of it and everything works fine, but in the checkout process page when I enter the coupon code nothing happens.when I check the ajax result with firebug, the response is empty. any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Do you get apply coupon button in checkout steps ?

Comment: yes I do, it seems the problem is with the views pane which load the response of ajax, I don't know how to edit the view to show suitable response for my custom coupon type.

Comment: anybody can help why the coupon views pane returns null?